# How to have nested generators continue their logic while parent generators needs to stop?

Tags: python, generator

Lets say I have the following code

```
def top():
    counter = 0

    for ch in child_1():
        print(ch)
        counter += 1

        if counter > 2:
            break


def child_1():
    for ch in child_2():
        yield ch

    print("child_1 logic has finished")


def child_2():
    for ch in "123456789":
        yield ch

    print("child_2 logic has finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    top()
```

Is there a way to have top() method to exit in the middle of the iteration like I have the counter condition, but let the children to finish their logic? (get to the code after the yield statement)

I tried to use while loop and other python tricks but it all went unsuccessful, I don't think there's a way without modifying the nested generators to not be a generators but I'm trying my shot here :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop generator from within block in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164785/stop-generator-from-within-block-in-python)

Comment: I want it due to internal architecture issue we have, to make a workaround without a total refactor for the time being. This is the issue when simplifying it :D

Comment: If you need `top` to stop, but the children to keep going, maybe your logic is backwards and the children are really the `top`. However, going by your current example you are just bunny-hopping the child2 generator, meaning the `top` and `middle` are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the children to "finish" what they're doing (i.e. perform the rest of the iteration), keep a reference to the iterator, and exhaust it after you break:

```
def top():
    counter = 0

    iter_1 = child_1()
    for ch in iter_1:
        print(ch)
        counter += 1

        if counter > 2:
            break

    for _ in iter_1:
        pass
```

Comment: There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763084/how-to-efficiently-exhaust-an-iterator-in-a-oneliner) about ways to exhaust an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to stop the `top` loop. You just need to stop doing the logic in the `top` loop. You can do this by moving your condition to the top, and using `continue` instead of `break`.

```
def top():
    counter = 0

    for ch in child_1():
        if counter > 2: #continue here instead of break after
            continue

        counter += 1

def child_1():
    for ch in child_2():
        yield ch

    print("child_1 logic has finished")


def child_2():
    for ch in "123456789":
        yield ch

    print("child_2 logic has finished")
```

Comment: Only when the loop body ends with the condition.

Comment: @ILS - I wrote this based on their example. Give me more specific examples and I'll write more specific answers. I've been programming since hard-drives were made out of cassette tapes and I can't think of a single time that I needed to stop a parent loop and keep the children running. This is all patchwork.